# Undetectable and Unblocked auto-play

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, audio

Auto play getting muted in both firefox and chrome. How can we code, so it won't get blocked by browsers.

My Code :

```
  <audio id="audio1" src="https://notificationsounds.com/storage/sounds/file-sounds-1217-relax.mp3" autoplay="">
  <script>
     a = document.getElementById('audio1');
     
     a.onended = function(){setTimeout("a.play()", 1000)}
  </script>
```

Comment: It is a browser feature. You can not overwrite the user settings for obvious reasons.

Comment: You can't do exactly as you require - you need to wait for some user interaction.

Comment: Related to Chrome on why this cannot be done https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Comment: @AHaworth I got your point. How to do with user interaction. Play automatically upon `On click`

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want, but yes, I'd play on click event.

Comment: @AHaworth User take any action in body tag. it will start playing audio.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [browser feature](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/) and it is enforced by a policy. Your page must have some continuous activity in order to do so.

As suggested by the comments, you can indeed wait for `onClick` events in order to trigger your playback.

Technically speaking, the referenced document says that for a developer standpoint of view you can alter them to perform specific tests:

> You can disable the autoplay policy entirely by using a command line flag: chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required. This allows you to test your website as if user were strongly engaged with your site and playback autoplay would be always allowed.

> You can also decide to make sure autoplay is never allowed by disabling MEI and whether sites with the highest overall MEI get autoplay by default for new users. Do this with flags: chrome.exe --disable-features=PreloadMediaEngagementData, MediaEngagementBypassAutoplayPolicies.